# PFQueryTableViewController with localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization, parse-platform

Is there a way to make PFQueryTableViewController sort like NSStrings localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare?

Answer (score 0):

Héctor Ramos (Solutions Architect at Parse.com) answers (in an email):

> The localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare modified is iOS specific, however
>   PFQuerys are executed on Parse's backend. This kind of sorting is not
>   supported by Parse. I would suggest doing a query using the standard
>   sort, then sorting the resulting array on the client side using a
>   NSSortDescriptor with localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare.

Thank to Hector for his answer, which works - I did it. However it breaks pagination.